# How to reduce number of lines of code in autolayout programming in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

How to reduce the number of lines of code in autolayout programming swift?

This question is not regarding how to write autolayout programmatically, but rather reducing length of related code.

Below is my autolayout related code. As you can see, it is lengthy. My aim is to reduce number of lines of codes and to avoid duplications.

```
private func buildConstraints(){
        scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        descriptionTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        amountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        amountTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        currencyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        currencyTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            scrollview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.widthAnchor)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
            descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            descriptionLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SpentAmountViewOffset.height)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
            descriptionTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            descriptionTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            descriptionTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            amountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
            amountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            amountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            amountLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SpentAmountViewOffset.height)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            amountTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: amountLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
            amountTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            amountTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            amountTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SpentAmountViewOffset.height)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            currencyLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: amountTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
            currencyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            currencyLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            currencyLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SpentAmountViewOffset.height)
               ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            currencyTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currencyLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
            currencyTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            currencyTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            currencyTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SpentAmountViewOffset.height),
            currencyTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.bottom)
               ])
    }
```

Comment: LOL. That _is_ the reduced version! You should have seen what it was like when you had to call the NSLayoutConstraint initializer (before anchors were invented). — There is no built-in way to make it shorter. You could use a third-part constraint generator like SnapKit, though. https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit

Comment: You could create an object to handle these things for you, like how SnapKit works. But as someone who does everything programmatically, I don't find constraints to be that burdensome or obtrusive (particularly since the vast majority of them are copy and pasted). Seeing them in the view controller also makes the code read easier. If the view controller is to contain anything (given today's hypersensitivity toward bloated view controllers), I would like to think it should contain auto layout code.

Comment: I’m sure you have a reason to do this, but it goes without saying that the best way to reduce this code is to not have it at all. Just set up your constraints in IB in your storyboard or NIB. It gets you out of writing code at all. The other alternative, for programmatically created views, is to add them as arranged subviews of a stack view. Then, no constraints are needed.

Comment: If you are fine with only supporting iOS 13.0+, and this is a new project, I suggest you use SwiftUI.

Comment: You should checkout the visual format language for constraints. You can specify a sequence of constraints, horizontally or vertically, in a single string e.g "V:[topField]-10-[bottomField]" See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH27-SW1

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could reduce the number of lines / duplicate lines.

For example, use arrays with `.forEach` to perform identical tasks:

```
    // all subviews need translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    [scrollview, contentView, descriptionLabel, descriptionTextView, amountLabel, amountTextField, currencyLabel, currencyTextField].forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
```

and:

```
    // these subviews all have the same leading, trailing and height constraints
    [descriptionLabel, amountLabel, amountTextField, currencyLabel, currencyTextField].forEach {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            $0.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SpentAmountViewOffset.height)
        ])
    }

    // descriptionTextView has same leading and trailing constraints, but different height
    [descriptionTextView].forEach {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.leading),
            $0.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.trailing),
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0)
        ])
    }

    // top / vertical spacing / bottom constraints for contentView subviews
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
        descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
        amountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
        amountTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: amountLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
        currencyLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: amountTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
        currencyTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currencyLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.top),
        currencyTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: SpentAmountViewOffset.bottom)
    ])
```

Another option is to use a `UIStackView`, so you only need to apply leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to the stack view:

```
    // add subviews to stack view
    [descriptionLabel, descriptionTextView, amountLabel, amountTextField, currencyLabel, currencyTextField].forEach {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
    }

    // height constraint is the same for these views
    [descriptionLabel, amountLabel, amountTextField, currencyLabel, currencyTextField].forEach {
        $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SpentAmountViewOffset.height).isActive = true
    }

    // different height constraint for descriptionTextView
    descriptionTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true

    // set stackView spacing (vertical space between arranged subviews)
    stackView.spacing = SpentAmountViewOffset.top
```

And, if these are all of the elements you have in your scroll view, the stack view can take the place of the "contentView".